# hi. i have some issue using javascript. how to use var **mobile** as phone number in whatsapp api

Tags: javascript, function, whatsapp

I'm using Html + Javascript only.

html:

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="input-control">
<img src="pic/download.jpg" onclick="chat()">
```

Javascript:

```
function chat(){
    var **mobile** = document.getElementById("mobile").value
    location.href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=**"mobile"**&text=Hello%20World
}
```

Comment: Variable names cannot have asterisks in them.

Comment: In addition to Mark, check how to interpolate strings of concatenate them properly, u did a wrong usage in the URL. I think if you open your console you should see it is shouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as shown below.  But note that I commented out the line that will actually redirect the browser away from StackOverflow.

```js
function chat(){
    let mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
    
    //assemble the new URL
    let newUrl = `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${mobile}&text=Hello%20World`;
    alert(newUrl);

    /*** uncomment next line to redirect the browser ***/
    //location.href=newUrl;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="input-control">
<img src="pic/download.jpg" onclick="chat()">
```

Comment: Thank a lot Marc. Great solution